# Supplying a flask parameter in <> form produces 404?

Tags: python, flask, parameters

I am trying to do this kind of thing:

```
@app.route('/search?term=<param>')
def search_db(param):
   ...blah blah...
```

I distinctly remember the <> notation working to pass a parameter.
Yet in my example, accessing the path `/search?term=whatever` produces 404.

I know about request.args and I plan to use it, but I really don't understand why the above does not work. Is it because of the "?"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seems like a mix up of two concepts. The `flask` routes with parameters and the `<>` notation are like this:

```
@app.route('/product/<name>')
def get_product(name):
    return "The product is " + str(name)
```

More on that check out the flaks tutorial on [routes](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-tutorial-routes/).

While the classical http parameters with `?` in the url work with the  `request.args.get` method.

Comment: I realize that.
What I did't understand is how this is handled and fails.

Seems that flask first intercepts "?" and expects an argument and stops itself from just reading the whole thing before variable '<>' as part of the path.

I would expect both things to work at the same time, but makes sense that they don't.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter name is `term`, you should write:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    term = request.args.get('term')
```